# This Regex is validating a URL and only this URL wrongly. Why?

Tags: python, regex, validation

```
  &copy 2014 <a href="http://www.fairfaxmedia.co.nz">Fairfax New Zealand Limited</a><br/>
  <a href="/about-stuff/legal/25044/privacy-policy">Privacy</a><!--  |
```

The above is the offending section in my HTML document.

Below is my regex. It works on every other URL in my document. Except this one.

```
urliter = re.finditer(r'(http://|https://)([\w]+\.[\w\.]+\/?)([\w\/\.]+")',lines)

urlMatches = defaultdict(list)
for match in urliter:
    urlMatches[match.group(2)].append(match.group())
```

When I view the output, for some reason, `www.fairfaxmedia.co.nz` cuts off the `z` at the end, so it only shows `www.fairfaxmedia.co.n` for `group(2)`

I can't figure out why this would be?

Also, question #2 - how would I only search for URLs in quotations, but leave the quotations out of the match?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex uses capturing group:

- `(http://|https://)` matches (and captures in group 1) the `http` part
- `([\w]+\.[\w\.]+\/?)` captures in the second group
- `([\w\/\.]+")` captures in the third group

Since you put a `+` in `([\w\/\.]+")`, the character class `[\w\/\.]` cannot match no character. Meaning that in `http://www.fairfaxmedia.co.nz"` the last group has to match at least `z"`.

Hence, the `z` cannot be in the second group (which is the one you're calling), illustration [here](http://regex101.com/r/jE4aE9).

If you want to simply separate the domain name from the rest of your URL, you can tweak your regex to:

```
"(https?://(\w+\.[\w.]+)(/?[\w/.-]*))"
```

The whole URL (without quotes) is in capturing group 1, the domain name in capturing group 2, the rest in capturing group 3: see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/oQ3eJ6).

Answer (score 0):

For searching for text in quotations, but leaving quotations out of the match you can use lookaround assertions.

For example (core regexp taken from Robins answer)

```
(?<=\")(https?://(\w+\.[\w.]+)(/?[\w\/\.]*))(?=\")
```